# Myself word gives an error in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have a problem in Netlogo when I use "myself" word
this is the code i am using in my project

```
    ask players [
          if ([owner] of the-ball != nobody) [
            ifelse([team] of ([owner] of the-ball) = [team] of myself and (myself != [target] of the-ball) )[
              set team-have-ball? true
            ] [
              set team-have-ball? false
            ]
          ]
]
```

the error says There is no agent for MYSELF to refer to.

Comment: Could you please provide your `breed` and `breed-own` statements so we can see which `turtle` types have the variable names you are using? I copied your code and added some `breeds` and did not get the error.

Comment: Hard to be sure, but I suspect you have confused `self` with `myself`. They mean very different things.